# Entity Framework and Web API/REST - Joining to list properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've created an web API app using EF (Code First, .NET Framework 4.5), and I have a class that links between two other classes, e.g., a person and a car, in order to track the specific year of the car for that person. This allows only a single entry required for each Make/Model in the Cars table, and a person could have multiple instances of any Make/Model of car. It looks something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public List<PersonCar> Cars {get; set;}
}

public class PersonCar
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Car {get; set;}
    public int Year {get; set;}
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public string Make {get; set;}
    public string Model {get; set;}
}
```

I need a controller that returns all Persons that drive a specific Make/Model of car, but I'm unable to create the proper query to join these tables. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonsByCarId(int carId)
{
    IQueryable<Person> Persons = db.Persons.Include(
    p => p.Cars.Where(
        c => c.Car.Id == carId)
    .Select(c => c.Car));
return Persons;
}
```

I've tried several variations of this by changing the sequence of the Where and Select statements, but consistently get an exception that includes this message:

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
```

I've been unable to find examples of how to properly join these tables/objects to return the list of persons. Can anyone tell me the proper way to structure this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Any()` extension which returns a `boolean` that you can use in the `Where` clause

```
IQueryable<Person> Persons = db.Persons
         // you can also do .Include("Car") here if you need Car property eager-loaded
                              .Where(p => p.Cars.Any(c => c.Car.Id == carId));
return Persons;
```

Comment: @AD Net - out of interest how are you associating person and car in person car?  Does the above return more than 1 person?

Comment: EF is smart enough to figure it out.